# Installing Python telnetlib module

Tags: python, module, installation

I'm trying to install a python module named telnetlib on my Ubuntu 15.4 OS.

I tried:

```
$ pip install telnetlib
```

but I get errors:

```
root@c-Peppy:~# pip install telnetlib
Collecting telnetlib
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement telnetlib (from  versions: )
No matching distribution found for telnetlib
root@c-Peppy:~#
```

I tried installing telnetlib as well as telnetlib3 but all give me the same results.

Here is the python documentation for telnetlib:
    https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html

Any help on how to install that module will be highly appreciated.

Comment: f it turns out you do not have it, its just one .py file. The 2.7 version is at hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/telnetlib.py and the 3.4 version is at hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/telnetlib.py. The latter is essentially the same as what's installed with Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 - there are some differences in comments and using True instead of 1, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that telnetlib is a library, you don't need to install the module as long as you have python.  You can just do
`import telnetlib`

from either the python interpreter or your python program.

In general, if its in the docs.python.org library, it's built into python.  If you are trying to install something with pip and having issues, try searching on pypi.python.org to see if the name is slightly different than you'd expect

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to python and that answer helped me a LOT! :D